# How to keep textarea text static when adding new text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<textarea>` that has text added to it based on some javascript. It all works great. The only problem is, when the text is added, it replaces what was already there. Not sure how to stop this from happening, and make it just add to what is in there already.

#### js:

```
function addNote0(text, element_id) {
document.getElementById(element_id).value += text;


var tabTextRows = ['','','','','',''];

$('.note').click(function(){
  var fret = $(this).index() - 1;
  var line = $(this).parent().index() -1;
  updateNote(fret, line);
});

function updateNote(fret, line){
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<tabTextRows.length;i++){
    if(i == line) tabTextRows[i]+='-'+fret+'-';
    else tabTextRows[i]+='---';
    $('#tabText').val(tabTextRows.join('\n'));
  }
}}

window.onload = function() {
  addNote0('','tabText');
};
```

#### textarea that is being added to:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="24" id="tabText" name="text">--
--
--
--
--
--</textarea>
```

So every time I click on a `<td>` it replaces the current "--" that is in there. I want it to just add to that. Any thoughts?

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsLaX/) of it. You will see what I mean when you click on the Xs

Comment: Could you demonstrate with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Added working fiddle in an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to just initialize your `tabTextRows` array in the beginning to:

`var tabTextRows = ['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'];`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsLaX/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I feel rather retarded for not thinking of this. So thanks again! :D

Comment: No problem. Everybody has those moments. ;) I'm just glad I could help.

Comment: Do not feel obligated to help on this, as you totally answered the question. But do you know how I could make it add an additional dash if the value sent is a double digit number, rather than single digit?

Comment: Here you go. Not too bad. http://jsfiddle.net/jsLaX/2/ Notice the changes `var strlen = fret.toString().length;` and `else tabTextRows[i] += strlen == 1 ? '---' : '----';`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just putting in new content, grab the old content and concatenate it with your new content, then put that inside your textarea.

Comment: Could you possible elaborate a bit?